# How to create and where to place a tailwind-merge config file

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3, tailwind-in-js

i am using the tailwind-merge package to merge tailwind classes,

but i've modified the tailwind classes in the tailwind config, like so

> module.exports = {
> content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
> theme: {
> fontSize: () => {
> const fontSize = {};
>
> for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i += 0.25) {
> fontSize[i] = `${i}rem`;
> }
>
> return fontSize;
> },
> },
> plugins: [],
> }

the problem is now,

"text-primary text-2" resolves to text-2 ( or whichever comes last )
but text-primary is color whereas text-2 is font-size,

i think i can redefine the tailwind-merge config object with the same function as above,
what i do not know is how i can generate the tailwind-merge config file and where should i place it in my vite app

i tried removing all my modifications from the tailwind-config file and THEN it works as expected so the problem is my modification to the tailwind config

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my text-shadow utility class.